# How to disable a JavaScript function after page Page.IsPostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Currently, I have a very simple div that has a display: none; property. When the page loads, I call $("#MyDiv").show(); to make the div popup and show to the user on a delay. From there they can enter in information to the form and submit it with an asp.net button.

Once the user enters in the information and submits the form, it will post back to the same page but it will then run the JavaScript function again and it will show the div again. How would I disable this function after postback?

I know that you can use the code:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack){}
```

But I am not sure how to disable the function. This is what my function looks like to show the div, pretty simple:

```
function testpopup() {
        setTimeout(function () { $("#MyDiv").show(); }, 1500);
    };
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Ok I figured out a way to do it. I pretty much set an input field hidden with the value of N like so:

`<input type="hidden" id="IsFormSubmitted" value="N" runat="server" />`

Then I made the function evaluate and set the value of the input field to Y like so:

'

```
function Password() {
        var val = document.getElementById("IsFormSubmitted");
        if(val.value == "N")
        {
            setTimeout(function () { $("#MyDiv").show(); }, 1500);
            val.value = "Y";
        }
    };
```

Thanks for all the direction :)

Comment: on the client side, by setting a cookie or localstorage

Comment: see if it is of any use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Inside if(!Page.IsPostBack), add RegisterStartupScript to add your function to the page

Comment: Is it required that you have that delay on page load? If not, put a runat="server" on your div and give it an ID. Then when page first loads just have your div showing. Then in your IsPostBack hide your div divID.Style.Add("display", "none");.

Comment: Hmm Ok I will try and work with these responses and get back to you when I have it completed. 

Do you think its better to have the Page.IsPostBack code in the aspx.cs file or just in the javascript in the aspx file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can also consider this approach - adding a HiddenField control in your aspx page where it marks whether the form has been submitted or not.

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hfIsFormSubmitted" value="" runat="server"/>
```

With that, once the submit button `OnClick` event is triggered, you can assign a value to the hidden field, e.g. `hfIsFormSubmitted.Value = "submitted";`. Then examine this value in your JS code to decide whether or not the show() function needs to run.

Comment: Thank you woody. I figured out a way through your example to make it work. I added it to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to achieve result you want.
1. Do not include `$("#MyDiv").show();` into `$(document)ready...`. Instead

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "showdiv", "$("#MyDiv").show();", true);
    }
}
```

2. Put your div with all controls into UpdatePanel.